# removing all classes for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulty removing all classes on an element and then adding the one I want on different pages using a switch statement

```
$(document).ready(function() {
switch (window.location.pathname) {
  case '/':
  $("body").removeClass().addClass('homepage');
  case '/users/sign_up':
  $('body').removeClass().addClass('contentpage');
}
});
```

Im not quite sure if document.ready is what i need either ?

My problem is that my selector isn't just body anymore, it is a class, but it could be one of a few class names.. How would i say "get the body tag no matter its class, remove all the classes and then add what i need"?

All that's happening at the moment is the extra class names are being applied

Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Pardon me , but if you want the body ( no matter what classes it has) you still can use `$("body")`.... am I missing something ?

Comment: well that's what thought but it wasn't working for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem with the `ready` callback. But you forget a `break` in your `switch`, which made the `'homepage'` class always replaced with `'contentpage'` :

```
$(function() {
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
      case '/':
         document.body.className = 'homepage';
         break;
      case '/users/sign_up':
         document.body.className = 'contentpage';
         break;
    }
});
```

Note that I used the `className` property instead of jQuery's functions, it's much simpler here.

Comment: dystroy (hi)  , was i missing something here ? ( can you have a look at my comment to him?)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm not sure of what you meant

Comment: @dystroy The code he wrote ( leave aside the break part) - should work! `$("body").removeClass().addClass('homepage');` -- will remove the classes from body and will set its own class

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes it should

Comment: went back to the original code, didnt work, added the breaks in and my code does work, though I think dystroy solution is much cleaner and efficient

Comment: @Richlewis Ofcourse. he's dystroy. (ps never thought what will happen if no breaks in a switch code...)

Comment: @RoyiNamir In C, Java, JavaScript and most languages with the `switch` construct, the execution goes to the following `case` if the `break` is missing. It's sometimes convenient but most often a bug, that's while it has been changed is some more modern languages (most notably the [go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch)).

Comment: moral of the story here for me is to check my code more thoroughly, though learned something new here :-)

Answer (score 0):

As read on [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

```
$("body").removeClass(function() {
    return $(this).attr("class");
});
```

so in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
        case '/':
            $("body").removeClass(function(){return $(this).attr("class")}).addClass('homepage');
            break;
        case '/users/sign_up':
            $('body').removeClass(function(){return $(this).attr("class")}).addClass('contentpage');
            break;
    }
});
```

EDIT: now with breaks

Comment: This is both wrong (read my answer) and incredibly complex for such a simple thing to do.

Comment: true, I didn't set the break as well. Although Richlewis stated that the selector wasn't body anymore. In your case it becomes way more difficult for the programmer to select the right elements (document.getElementsByClassName.. I hate that one). For that reason I choose to use jQuery. Especially when this is excecuted only once per page-reload; the computers of today won't give much lag on such a simple calculation

Answer (score -1):

using jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
        case '/':
            $("body").attr('class', '').addClass('homepage');
        case '/users/sign_up':
            $('body').attr('class', '').addClass('contentpage');
    }
});
```

Comment: When the pathname is "/", this sets the class to contentpage.